# BoundField "child" in aspx

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a gridview with a columns, and inside that columns I have boundfields.

```
<Columns> 
<asp:BoundField headerStyle-Wrap="false" ItemStyle-Wrap="false" HeaderText="A" DataField="A" />
<asp:BoundField headerStyle-Wrap="false" ItemStyle-Wrap="false" HeaderText="B" DataField="B" />
<asp:BoundField headerStyle-Wrap="false" ItemStyle-Wrap="false" HeaderText="C" DataField="C" />
<asp:BoundField headerStyle-Wrap="false" ItemStyle-Wrap="false" HeaderText="D1" DataField="D1" />
<asp:BoundField headerStyle-Wrap="true" ItemStyle-Wrap="false" HeaderText="D2" DataField="D2" />
<asp:BoundField headerStyle-Wrap="true" ItemStyle-Wrap="false" HeaderText="D3" DataField="D3" />
</Columns>
```

I have a picture that explains what I have, and what I am looking to achieve, here it goes:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as you have `ItemTemplate` to keep your design in gridview cell, you also have `HeaderTemplate` to customise header design. Googling took me to [this simple article](http://www.advancesharp.com/blog/1077/gridview-multiple-header-rows)